# How to calculate quantiles for Normal-Inverse Gaussian distribution in Excel

Tags: excel, distribution

Quite simply, I'm trying to determine the [Normal-Inverse Gaussian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal-inverse_Gaussian_distribution) distribution equivalent of `NORM.INV` (for a standard Normal distribution) in Excel. I know that this is possible in R with the `qnig` function or in Matlab, but I would like to know if there exists an implementation in Excel.